# Install standalone instance on cluster server with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, clustering

I've a cluster instance in 2016 SP1 version on Windows 2016 server. All work fine.
I want to install a new instance in standalone mode (version 2008) on one server of this cluster. The data disk of this new instance will be localdisk.

I want to know if the standalone installation will work without broke or impact cluster instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a hell of a bad idea, but it might work. I have done something similar in the past because it was the only possible solution and I can confirm that it works.

The only thing to be careful about is the versions: you will probably get warnings about installing sql server 2008 on Windows 2016. Also, keep in mind that it's not supported (which doesn't mean it won't work).

However, this is something I would never do in production: do yourself a favour and find a different machine for that SQL Server 2008 standalone instance: at least, you won't get shared features incompatibilities and the like.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've found a solution to be able to install a 2016 Sql server standalone instead of 2008 version. So now i'll install this standalone version on the cluster which have the same version of SQL Server. I think it will work too ?

Comment: Same version is much less problematic. It should work

Answer (score 0):

Installing an SQL Server 2008 may overwrite shared libraries, so as spaghettidba says, get a new standalone server.

I remember some years ago we did something like this, we had some issues, nothing to stop completely the cluster operation but we had some issues, don't remember exactly what was, but at the end the suggestion from MS support was to always install older versions first and newer versions later to avoid any incompatibility issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've found a solution to be able to install a 2016 Sql server standalone instead of 2008 version. So now i'll install this standalone version on the cluster which have the same version of SQL Server. I think it will work too ?

Comment: Yes, I have installed on my shop both clustered and local instances of SQL server 2016, in the same machine.